# Have Carp report correct caller from sub helper

Tags: perl

How do I have Perl's `Carp` report the caller location by skipping (or going back) one level of the `caller` ?

Given my own local sub in `MY_Package`:

```
package MY_package;

sub logme
{
    # some stuff I need logme for but the stack this example suffices
    carp shift;
}
```

Now, whenever I use `MY_package::logme`, how (or can I ?) get `carp` to skip the `logme` location and instead show from where `MY_package::logme` was called?

**UPDATED** based on @Joshua's answer, I'm adding this for clarity:

Actually, the case/question is when I use `MY_package::logme` withing another helper sub of a different module (or script).

So, given:

```
    # MY_package.pm
3|
4| sub logme {
5|     my $arg = shift or croak('Not enough arguments supplied');
6|     print "Yay, got $arg\n";
7| }
8|
```

I'd use it like this:

```
     # test_script.pl
 5|
 6| use MY_package;
 7|
 8| sub helper {
 9|    MY_package::logme(@_);
10| }
11|
12| helper ("balh blah blah");
...
80| helper ($foo, $bar, $baz);
...
99| helper ("I hope my question is more clear now");
```

Given the above, and the calls from lines 12, 80 and 99, the `logme` and `croak` (or `carp`) from `MY_package` would always report on line 9 as the error! I wish to report the point where the `helper` sub was called from...

Comment: Provided an update to my answer based on your clarification. Though you are correct re: `croak` and `carp`. They appear to be the same. Don't know why I thought otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Both [Carp](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html) and [caller](http://perldoc.perl.org/caller.html) go back up the call stack and their output can be parsed for a report. `Carp` routines `carp` and `cluck` print to `STDERR` so to use them for the purpose of this question one would have to employ the `$SIG{__WARN__}` hook. But, `Carp::longmess` simply returns a string underlying those calls.

`Carp` routines print messages at the point at which they are called and cannot be reasonably asked to go to levels above, like one does with `caller($frameno)`. (Docs advise *against* the use of the variable `$Carp::CarpLevel` that messes with how `Carp` plays with call frames.) However, we can parse the string output of `longmess`.

The code posted here uses `Carp::Longmess()`, except for one additional example of `caller` (which can also be used to this purpose). For its basics review the output of

```
use Carp qw(longmess);
my @lm = split '\n', longmess();
```

Beware that some calls may get 'optimized away' and thus not be there for `Carp` to find them.

On the other hand, `@call = caller($fno)` gives an 11-long list about the frame `$fno`. There are subtleties in how subs and lines are reported. For example, this summarizes a call

```
my $caller = (caller(1))[3] . ' l.' . (caller)[2];
```

This allows one to 'walk the stack,' by iterating over the frame number, also shown below.

Error tracing is hard and adding another call after the error in my opinion adds to trouble.  This post only aims to show a basic way to see the call stack, and to have a sub parse the trace so to omit itself. There are modules for this out there, for example [Devel::StackTrace](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::StackTrace).

---

In the code below calls are made in `main::` to trigger the sub that would log the error, via subs spread over two packages and main. They 'die' with or without `eval`, attempt a bad `open`, and in one case a mere message is sent (no error).

These calls are printed, along with the logger's output, built using `Carp::longmess`. Reporting omits the logger itself, as if it came from a level above. There is also a **separate example slipped in** of how to build the **full trace by `caller`**, and **indent output by the stack-frame level** of the sub.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
$| = 1;

package LogPack;
use Carp qw(longmess);
sub logme {
    my ($err, @other) = @_;
    chomp($err);
    my @lm = split '\n', longmess();
    # longmess() return:
    #   first line:  message passed if any, then "at pack::sub line num."
    #   all others:  "pack::sub(args) called at sub line num"
    print "Message: \"$err\":\n";
    # Print first line if error message doesn't show where it was issued
    # (If it comes from eval it does, otherwise it may not)
    if ( $err =~ m/line \d+\./ ) {
        print "$_\n" for ( map { s/\(.*\)/()/; $_ } @lm[1..$#lm] );
    } else { 
        print "$_\n" for ( map { s/\(.*\)/()/; $_ } @lm );
    }
    return 1;
}

package ThrowPack;
sub throw_die_pack {
    # First a separate example: get stack-trace; indent by frame number 
    my $rstack = main::get_call_stack(); 
    my $tno = "\t" x @$rstack;
    print $tno . "In ThrowPack::throw_die_pack()\n";
    print $tno . "Example: Show stack trace. Indented by frame number.\n";
    print $tno . "--- stack\n";
    print $tno . "$_\n"  for @$rstack;
    print $tno . "---------\n";
    # Now throw; it bubbles up, but handler call is outside!
    print $tno . "Will cook div by zero now (1/0) ... \n";
    my $res = 1/0;
}

package main;

sub err_handler   { LogPack::logme(@_); return 1 }
sub call_for_msg  { LogPack::logme(@_); return 1 }
sub open_nofile   {
    open my $fh, '<', "no_such_file.$$"  or err_handler($!);
    return 1;
}
sub call_err      { throw_die() }
sub call_err_pack { ThrowPack::throw_die_pack() }
sub throw_die     { eval { my $res = 1/0 } or err_handler($@); }

# Not necessary, just showing another way of tracing the call stack
sub get_call_stack() { 
    my $i = 1; # omit this call from trace
    my @strace;
    while ( my @call = caller($i++) ) {
        push @strace, "$call[1] line $call[2] in sub $call[3]";
    }
    return [ @strace ];
}

print "Starting main.\n";
print "1. Log a message when there is no error.\n";
call_for_msg("A string, no error.");
print "2. Call a sub that attempts to open a non-existent file ...\n";
open_nofile();
print "3. Call subs which throw 'die' and do eval ...\n";
# Need to control returns from code inside eval for 'eval { } or' to work
eval { call_err() } or err_handler($@); 
print "4. Call subs which 'die' without eval ...\n";
eval { call_err_pack() } or err_handler($@); 
print "Normal end.\n";
```

Output follows. **The print indented far to the right is a separate example of the trace via `caller`, indented by the (`"\t" x`) stack-frame number of the sub.** I find it of huge help when all calls are tagged this way, sometimes (GUI debugging comes to mind).

```
Starting main.
1. Log a message when there is no error.
Message: "A string, no error.":
at rept_err.pl line 45.
       main::call_for_msg() called at rept_err.pl line 67
2. Call a sub that attempts to open a non-existent file ...
Message: "No such file or directory":
at rept_err.pl line 44.
       main::err_handler() called at rept_err.pl line 47
       main::open_nofile() called at rept_err.pl line 70
3. Call subs which throw 'die' and do eval ...
Message: "Illegal division by zero at rept_err.pl line 52.":
       main::err_handler() called at rept_err.pl line 52
       main::throw_die() called at rept_err.pl line 50
       main::call_err() called at rept_err.pl line 72
       eval {...} called at rept_err.pl line 72
4. Call subs which 'die' without eval ...
                       In ThrowPack::throw_die_pack()
                       Example: Show stack trace. Indented  by frame number.
                       --- stack
                       rept_err.pl line 51 in sub ThrowPack::throw_die_pack
                       rept_err.pl line 74 in sub main::call_err_pack
                       rept_err.pl line 74 in sub (eval)
                       ---------
                       Will cook div by zero now (1/0) ... 
Message: "Illegal division by zero at rept_err.pl line 38.":
       main::err_handler() called at rept_err.pl line 74
Normal end.
```

Note that the call to subs which die without `eval`-ing doesn't show anything beyond the point of handler invocation, triggered by its `eval` in `main::` -- because that call started with the handler invocation. The error message still correctly shows the point of error but there is no trace to it. This is an important case: you use code (module, libs) with no access to, and an unhandled `die` hits you.

Comment: Intent, as stated, is to use `MY_package::logme` as a helper sub in any other script (or module). **But** when `MY_package::logme` outputs the `carp` msg it should do so from the other script (or module)'s calling point-of-view

Comment: How does logme() help? An error happened elsewhere, I take it, then what -- do you pass it ($!) to logme()?  You have to be very careful, it gets tricky if that's what you do.  Why do you call `carp` from a logger-helper?  I've written libraries for my own use which do related things, but only to reconstruct the stack, and they do report from their caller's perspective.  However, I call `carp` exclusively exactly where the error happened.

Comment: logme() does some other sweet stuff, which I'm not bringing into question, I know I can `carp` exclusively exactly where the error happened, but I want my cherry too:) I **do** know that logme() will **always** be called one level down from the any other script (or module).

Comment: Yes, that's the way I invoke `logme`, why would it matter? Also, I see that the docs discourage the use of `$Carp::CarpLevel`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `croak` function from `Carp`.

```
    # TestModule.pm
3|
4| sub this_method {
5|     my $arg = shift or croak('Not enough arguments supplied');
6|     print "Yay, got $arg\n";
7| }
8|
```

Now when you call that method from another script, it will report the error relative to where you called it, eg. doing this...

```
    # test_script.pl
5|
6| use TestModule;
7|
8| TestModule::this_method();
9|
```

Would yield the following error...

```
Not enough arguments supplied at test_script.pl line 8.
```

If you want a full stacktrace you can opt for `confess` instead of `croak`, which would give you this error...

```
Not enough arguments supplied at TestModule.pm line 5.
        TestModule::this_method() called at test_script.pl line 8
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, given your clarification, what you really need to do is catch the exception at the helper sub. Rather than catch it in the module, you need to propagate the error up by returning a falsey value (ie `return;`). At the helper sub we can then call `Module::method() or die` and the `or` condition will trigger, because `Module::method()` returned a falsy value.

```
    # MyPackage.pm
 1| package MyPackage;
 2| 
 3| sub logme {
 4|     my $arg = shift;
 5|     return if !$arg;
 6|     print "Yay, got $arg\n";
 7|     return 1;
 8| }
 9|
10| 1;

    # test_script.pl
 5| use MyPackage;
 6| use Carp qw( longmess );
 7| 
 8| sub helper {
 9|     MyPackage::logme(@_) or die(longmess('Not enough args'));
10| }
11| 
12| helper();
```

Alternatively... rather than have the error defined in your script file, you might opt to set the global `$EVAL_ERROR` (`$@`) variable, although this is sometimes frowned upon as it would overwrite that value if it had been set by another failed operation. Which is to say, in the event of cascading failures, you really want to know what the first failure was... so doing this is only acceptable in very simple functions where you want to be able to return different error messages.

```
    # MyPackage.pm
 1| package MyPackage;
 2| 
 3| sub logme {
 4|     my $arg = shift;
 5|     if ( !$arg ) {
 6|         $@ = 'Not enough arguments supplied';
 7|         return;
 8|     }
 9|     print "Yay, got $arg\n";
10|     return 1;
11| }
12| 
13| 1;

    # test_script.pl
 5| use MyPackage; 
 6| use Carp qw( longmess );
 7| 
 8| sub helper {
 9|     MyPackage::logme(@_) or die(longmess($@));
10| }   
11| 
12| helper();
```

Both the above implementations should gives you this error

```
Not enough args at test_script.pl line 12.
```

Also, there are modules on CPAN to provide better support for throwing and catching exceptions (just search for `throw`). I have not used them so I can't comment on them, but you might want to look into them.

**UPDATE**

A better option than setting `$@` would be to create a variable in your module to store the error, and a method to set/get that error.

```
    # MyModule.pm
 6| sub error {
 7|     my $msg = shift;
 8|     state $error;
 9|     if ($msg) {
10|         $error = $msg;
11|     }
12|     return $error;
13| }
14| 
15| sub logme {
16|     my $arg = shift;
17|     if ( !$arg ) {
18|         error('Not enough arguments supplied');
19|         return;
20|     }
21|     print "Yay, got $arg\n";
22|     return 1;
23| }
24|
25| 1;

    # test_script.pl
 8| sub helper {
 9|     MyPackage::logme(@_) or die( longmess( MyPackage::error() ) );
10| }
```

I'm using a `state` variable here, which is availble in perl > 5.10 (via `use feature 'state'`). If you have an old perl, `$error` would need to be a package global.

Comment: first see I clarified the question for you.... and I don't see why `croak` differs from `carp` even before I clarified the question...

Answer (score 0):

This questions is a little old now but the correct way to do this is to use `@CARP_NOT`.

### Example

```
package Helper;

use Carp;
our @CARP_NOT;

sub gonna_carp {
  carp("Error");
}

1;
```

---

```
package Something;

use Helper;
@Helper::CARP_NOT = ("Something");

sub do_thing {
  Helper::gonna_carp();
}

1;
```

---

Now when something calls Something::do_thing the carp will ignore Something.pm and go up again to the caller.

[cpanm link](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp#@CARP_NOT)